# Returning data from an API - How can I tell?

Tags: java, xml

I have a few questions that i am hoping to get some help with. I created the following code for a school project. The project is to build a java web app that allows the user to input their zipcode and a distance, and submit it to return the closest Best Buy store locations.

Now I have written this and ran it through NetBeans on a Glassfish Server, and it compiles and runs, showing my (Now unlabeled) fields and a submit button.

What my question(s) is(are):

1. Is there a way for me to tell if the java script is in fact connecting to the Best Buy API and returning the data?
2. How can I return the results to be output on the clients browser (with XML?). Currently when I click submit, the fields blank out and nothing else appears in the browser.

I have been at this for quite awhile, read days, (with a rather absent professor) and the answer is probably glaringly obvious, but my beginner programming experience is probably missing it.

Cheers

```
<%-- 
Document   : index.jsp
Created on : Apr 24, 2014, 3:42:41 PM
Author     : Admin
--%>
<%@page
import="com.mattwilliamsnyc.service.remix.*;,java.util.List;,java.util.ArrayList;"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Zip Code</title>
</head>
<body>
    <Form Method="post" action="index.jsp">
        <input type="text" name="zipcode"/>
        <input type="text" name="distance"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Search"/>
    </form>
    <%

        String zipcode = request.getParameter("zipcode");
        String distance = request.getParameter("distance");

        List<String> storeFilters   = new ArrayList<String>();

        storeFilters.add("area('zipcode','distance')");

        Remix remix = new Remix("6kzg5pqj73j29vrycjsgfvjt");   
        for (Store store : remix.getStores(storeFilters).list()) {
                System.out.println(store.getName());
                System.out.println(store.getPhone());
                System.out.println(store.getAddress());
                System.out.println();
            }
        %>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you shouldn't be using your computer from an Admin account!

Comment: @ErikAllik Does that have some effect on my problems?

Comment: nope, just for the record.

Comment: Didn't my answer fix your problem at all?

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant:

```
storeFilters.add("area('" + zipcode + "', '" + distance + "')");
```

instead of

```
storeFilters.add("area('zipcode','distance')");
```

The latter just constructs the constant string literal `"area('zipcode','distance')"` completely independent of the content of the variables `zipcode` and `distance`.